# How to forecast seasonal sales amount in R

Tags: r, forecasting

I want to forecast sales amount in a seasonal context. After read some webpages from [Quick-R](http://statmethods.net/advstats/timeseries.html), I tried to forecast sales amount data I have, though I don't understand some nouns (for example, lag).

Here are some code:

```
# load library
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(forecast)

# fake data

set.seed(4)
amount_2014 <- c(sample(3000:3500, 6), sample(4000:5000, 6))
set.seed(5)
amount_2015 <- c(sample(3000:3500, 6), sample(4000:5000, 6))
set.seed(6)
amount_2016 <- c(sample(3000:3500, 6), sample(4000:5000, 4))

sales <- data.frame(year = c(rep(2014, 12), rep(2014, 12), rep(2016, 10)),
                    month = c(1:12, 1:12, 1:10),
                    amount = c(amount_2014, amount_2015, amount_2016))

sales <- sales %>% mutate(Month = ymd(paste(year, month), truncated =2)) %>%
  arrange(Month)

sales_ts <- ts(sales$amount, start = c(sales$year[1], sales$month[1]),
               frequency = 12)

# first try
sales_ts_fc_1 <- forecast(sales_ts, h = 13)
sales_ts_fc_1  # the forecast for every month is same


# then try
auto.arima(sales_ts)
sales_ts_arima <- arima(sales_ts, order = c(0, 1, 0))
sales_ts_fc_2 <- forecast.Arima(sales_ts_arima, h = 13)
sales_ts_fc_2 # the forecst for evey month is very close
```

Both tries failed because the forecasted sales amount is not seasonal.

How to forecast the seasonal data like this?

Thanks!

Comment: [SO] is a Q&A site for self-contained, concrete *coding* questions. What you need is to learn time series analysis & forecasting. That isn't really what SO is for, & is too large to do within this framework.

Answer (score 0):

Add libraries

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(forecast)
```

Start by exploring the seasonality `plot(stl(sales_ts, s.window = 12))`. I think seasonality is not strong.

I actually get a unit root...?

```
> auto.arima(sales_ts)
Series: sales_ts 
ARIMA(0,1,0)
```

Also try to use Holt Winters which models seasonality `?HoltWinters`

Also read [this](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/9)

Comment: I just correct the typos. I will follow your advice. Thanks.